# Ruby: how to make a Hash from path more robust?

Tags: ruby, string, hash, dependency-injection

Assuming some hashes in the array only have path a.b or `{"a"=>{"b"=>"someanswer"}}`, how do I make the below code robust enough to display the last element without dieing?

```
path = ("a.b.c.d")
arrayOfHashes.collect {|hash| path.split(".").inject(hash) { |hash, key| hash[key] }}
```

Comment: Do you want to display the last element that you have on hand, or try to display 'a.b.c.d` and return `nil` if it can't be reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifications are not complete. Something like that?

```
arrayOfHashes = [{"a" => {"b" => "hello"}}, {"a" => {"b" => {"c" => {"d" => "response"}}}}]
path = "a.b.c.d"
arrayOfHashes.map do |hash| 
  path.split(".").inject(hash) do |acc, key|
    acc.is_a?(Hash) ? acc[key] : acc
  end
end
#=> ["hello", "response"]
```

Comment: sorry I meant to display the last element in every case, rather than displaying nil. `#=> ["aa","response"]`